# How to make tmux pane determine the command running deeper than the SSH session

Tags: ssh, tmux

I have some configurations in my .tmux.conf binding hjkl to navigate between tmux-panes and vim-splits seamlessly.

```
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_title}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"
```

Everything works well until I SSH to remote machines. When my pane is running an SSH session then:

- `pane_title` is always the host (running tmux) name (doesn't change if I enter vim on the remote server).
- `pane_current_command` is always `ssh` (doesn't change if I enter vim on the remote server).

I would like to extend those key-binding so they work the same on remote servers.

If possible a solution that doesn't require neasted tmux is preferred.

EDIT:
I finally decided to install https://github.com/sunaku/tmux-navigate